# How to keep the cursor's vertical position when page up/down in vim?

Tags: vim, cursor-position

I want to keep my cursor's vertical position when page up (`Ctl-U`) or down (`Ctl-D`). This is particularly useful when I am in a long python function and want to figure out block structures by indentation.

Current behavior when I page down:

```py
if foo:
    xxx = yyy
    ^ <-- cursor was here before page down
    ... many content in between ...
    while bar:
        xxx = yyy
    ^      ^ <-- cursor jumped here after page down
    ^ <-- I want it to stay here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to give a look at `'startofline'`/`'sol'` option.

By default it is `on`, but the description reads

> When off the cursor is kept in the same column
> (if possible).  This applies to the commands: CTRL-D, CTRL-U, CTRL-B,
> CTRL-F, "G", "H", "M", "L", gg, and to the commands "d", "<<" and ">>"
> with a linewise operator, with "%" with a count and to buffer changing
> commands (CTRL-^, :bnext, :bNext, etc.).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Enlico!